# CodePro: where to find the plugin for Intellij Idea?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, intellij-plugin

I have **Codepro analytics** plugin installed on my eclipse `https://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest/3.7` which I am using since may days. However I don't see any new version coming up for this. I am now shifting to Intellij Idea for my development. However does anybody know that is there any Codepro available for Intellij or how can I use this eclipse plugin in Intellij?

Answer (score 0):

There's no IntelliJ plugin for CodePro and you can't use Eclipse plugins in IDEA.

However, there's a feature in IntelliJ IDEA called ['Inspections'](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/discover-intellij-idea.html#Inspections): built-in static code analysis tools that help you find probable bugs, locate dead code, detect performance issues, and improve the overall code structure. Its functionality should match that of CodePro's and maybe even exceed it.

Check [this IntelliJ documentation page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html) as well.